# Can I route a call via SIP based on a phone number?

Tags: calls, sip

My Android 4.0.4 phone supports SIP. However, the options when to use the "Internet calling" are very limited: "For all calls", "Only for Internet calls", "Ask for each call".

I would like to use Internet (SIP) calls for all calls outside of my area code (e.g. all international and long-distance calls should go via SIP, and local calls should go via my regular voice account).

Is there any application, patch or tweak that can help me with that? My phone is rooted.

Comment: "Find me an app that does X" questions are generally not on-topic here. (Please review the [FAQ].)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Csipsimple indeed does the job if you want to use it as your SIP client. If you prefer the built-in SIP client, try the [Advanced Dialer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.baychev.android.advanceddialer).

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a program called CSipSimple.  It let's you customize not only whether certain calls are routed, through a Sip provider, but which Sip provider as well.  With CSipSimple, the filters are based on regular expressions so there's a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

**Sipdroid** has routing capabilities while also providing basic bluetooth headset support which CSipSimple still lacks.

I've been able to set it up so that calls with certain prefixes go through device's GSM voice link and all the rest go via SIP. This has had a bonus of blocking short "premium" numbers, which proliferate in European GSM networks and are designed to take advantage of careless cell phone users.

https://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/

BTW, both Sipdroid and CSipSimple are *opensource* projects, so if you need some *really* advanced routing it is not impossible to code the required logic directly into the app.